# Insert videos from media module into Ckeditor

Tags: wysiwyg, files, media, nodes

I've been working the media module and inserting images with the ckeditor media widget and It's been great.

I've also used some embbed media plugins to add vimeo and youtube media elements wonderfully.

But when I try to insert some of this media into the ckeditor it only inserts the rendered image form this media instead of the widget i get when I render the media in a node.

I need to know if I have to configure the file-types/ output in the media module or config anything in the ckeditor.

Thanks

Comment: enable drupal media plugin from ckeditor setting page

Comment: As I said, I have it already working fine, the media plugin let me select images and ther image-cache versions, but when I pick a video it only render a picture of it.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I've been having trouble having videos from the media module render in CKEditor fields, even after saving, and viewing the rendered node page.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is just how it works with the media module.  You might could experiment with the http://drupal.org/sandbox/DevinCarlson/1823634 to select the view modes for files displayed inserted into wysiwyg editor.

Comment: For future reference, the module linked is a submodule added in media itself already.

Answer (score 0):

[insert_video module](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert_video) adds an Insert button to video fields managed by the Media module. It allows you to insert video markup into your WYSIWYG by choosing a pre-defined formatter.